# App crashed with error while deleting objects from coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, ios7

I am storing some data in data. when i click on button the data in the coredata will be delete.
I am using the below code.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[YPOAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[YPOAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectModel];

for (NSEntityDescription *entity in model) {
     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
     [fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:NO];
     NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
     NSLog(@"objects ===%d",objects.count);
     for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in objects)
     {
            [context deleteObject:managedObject];
     }
}

NSError *err;

[context save:&err];
```

It's getting an error and app is crashed that is **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x7e3937f0**

How to fix this crash issue. Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have any entities with relationships with a `Delete Rule` of `No Action`?  That could lead to that sort of error.

Comment: Use [context deleteObjects:] instead of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting please weather you have that particular object or not ?

```
if ([ListObjetcts existingObjectWithID:objects.objectID error:&error])
    {

    }
```